# Workaround for Update/Insert with WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having a serious brain fart over this but essentially i have a table that looks similar to this -

```
+  id  +  staff_id   +    location       +    date    + dismiss_boolean + 
+------+-------------+-------------------+------------+-----------------+
+   1  +      22     + Bedfordshire      + 2011-11-01 +        0        +
+   2  +      22     + Hertfordshire     + 2011-11-02 +        1        +
+   3  +      16     + Bedfordshire      + 2011-12-01 +        0        +
+   4  +      17     + Bedfordshire      + 2011-11-22 +        0        +
+   5  +      77     + Hertfordshire     + 2011-11-01 +        1        +
+   6  +      77     + Cambridgeshire    + 2011-11-01 +        1        +
```

What i'm after is (in a single query) -

If the row exists, ie: there is a row where staff_id = 6 and location = Bedfordshire, then UPDATE the row **only** if the date field is older than **X** date.

Otherwise, if the row doesn't exist (there isn't a row where staff_id = 6 and location = Bedfordshire) then INSERT the data as a new row.

Usually you would use -

```
INSERT....ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
```

But you can't, iirc, use WHERE clauses in the UPDATE statement if using ON DUPLICATE. And again you can't use UNIQUE Indexes on the location and staff_id fields due to duplicates.

So i'm after a query along the lines of -

```
IF(
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `notifications` WHERE `staff_id` = '6' AND `location` = 'Bedfordshire') > 0
, UPDATE `notifications` SET `dismiss_boolean` = '1', `date` = '2011-12-10'  WHERE `staff_id` = '6' AND `location` = 'Bedfordshire' AND `date` < '2011-12-10' 
, INSERT INTO `notifications` (`staff_id`, `location`, `date`, `dismiss_boolean`) VALUES ('6', 'Bedfordshire', '2011-12-10', '1')
)
```

But that throws syntax errors and it's incorrect use of the IF function from what I remember.

So has anyone got any ideas how I can accomplish this? The only solution i can think of is to query the table prior to updating or insert the data but as said, ideally i want to do this in a single query.

Any help will be appreciated as I've been rattling around this problem for most of the day and I've yet to come up trumps searching Google/Stackoverflow.

Comment: will perform all inserts / updates in this way? how was it possible to create duplicate using this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is still actual, but just for reference:

```
INSERT INTO notifications
    (staff_id, location, `date`, dismiss_boolean
VALUES ('6', 'Bedfordshire', '2011-12-10', '1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    dismiss_boolean = if(VALUES(`date`) < '2011-12-10',
                         VALUES(dismiss_boolean),
                         dismiss_boolean),
    `date` =          if(VALUES(`date`) < '2011-12-10',
                         VALUES(`date`),
                         `date`);
```